# How to write bottom to top vertically with css

Tags: html, css

How to write vertically from bottom to up with HTML and CSS? I have tried many things writing-mod:tb-rl; but the issue not yet solved.

[image]

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/h4z69c6w/

Answer (score 1):

Create a `div` with class `rotate`

```
<div class="rotate"> Hello World </div>
```

Then define the CSS class

```
.rotate {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -o-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: The default value of transform origin is already 50% 50% so it's not necessary to add this.

Comment: Happy to help. Kindly mark my answer as accepted. It will help others to find correct answer quickly. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

try using transforms.

```
.rotate {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.rotate {
  /* make width fit content */
  display: inline-block;
  /* rotate 90 degrees counterclockwise */
  /* and move down on 100% of its height */
  /* (actually width, but when rotated it looks like height) */
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(-100%);
  /* perform this transformation relatively to the top left corner of block */
  transform-origin: top left;
  
  /* styles for demo */
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="rotate">Profile</div>
```

But beware that transformed element takes its position the same if it wouldn't be transformed. So in case you'd have some siblings with text it will be overlapping them. Demo:

```css
.rotate {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(-100%);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  
  /* just styles for current demo */
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="rotate">Profile</div>
  <div>Some other text</div>
  <div>Some other text</div>
  <div>Some other text</div>
</div>
```

In this case you can apply absolute positioning to this element. Demo:

```css
.container {
  /* make absolute positioning relative to container */
  position: relative;
  /* some offset for its not rotated text */
  /* need to be equal rotated element height + offset from rotated element */
  padding-left: 45px;
}

.rotate {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(-100%);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  
  /* apply absolute positioning */
  position: absolute;
  /* move element to the left */
  left: 0;
  
  /* just styles for demo */
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="rotate">Profile</div>
  <div>Some other text</div>
  <div>Some other text</div>
  <div>Some other text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @KapilGoyal Mark answer that helped you as accepted (green check to the left of answer).